# How to display the databases content in a popover by ID (with Foreach)

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table containing list of users, when i hover selector button "myuser" it is necessary that a popover is displayed with the mail of user select.

The problem is if I click on button: the popover displays the email of all users each time.

```php
<td
  class="classgroup"
  tabindex="0"
  id="classgroup"
  data-html="true"
  data-toggle="popover"
  data-trigger="hover"
  data-trigger="focus"
  title="<?php foreach ($client as $person): ?><?php echo $person->nom; ?><?php endforeach;?>"
  data-content="<?php foreach ($client as $person): ?><?php echo $person->email; ?><?php endforeach;?>">
  myuser
</td>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Well yeah, if you use a foreach loop and go over all records _inside_ the `title` and `data-content` attributes you are creating there, then what else did you expect? Surely there should not be a loop in _that_ place, it should only output the data of the current record there …?

Comment: Can you show the rest of your PHP code? You are only showing a snippet of the single TD cell.

Comment: `<?php foreach ($client as $person): ?><?php echo $person->nom; ?><?php endforeach;?>` can be rewritten as `<?php foreach ($client as $person):  echo $person->nom;  endforeach;?>` no need to close and open the php tag after each instruction

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($client as $person): ?>
<td
  class="classgroup"
  tabindex="0"
  id="classgroup"
  data-html="true"
  data-toggle="popover"
  data-trigger="hover"
  data-trigger="focus"
  title="<?php echo $person->nom; ?>"
  data-content="<?php echo $person->email; ?>">
  myuser
</td>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

moving the foreach loop out will create as many table cells as items in the array you are looping. Adapt it to your desired output (like splitting in multiple lines)